# flutter changed value with set state falls after refresh

Tags: flutter, dart, colors, setstate

In the code below, after pressing the key, the color of the program's theme changes, the problem is that upon exiting and entering the program, the color of the program changes to the previous state. What is your suggestion?

```
class _FeedScreenState extends State<FeedScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;

    return Scaffold(
      extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
      backgroundColor:
          width > webScreenSize ? webBackgroundColor : mobileBackgroundColor,
      appBar: width > webScreenSize
          ? null
          : AppBar(
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                      bottomLeft: Radius.circular(25.0),
                      bottomRight: Radius.circular(25.0))),
              toolbarHeight: 40,
              backgroundColor: d,
              foregroundColor: w,
              bottomOpacity: 0.1,
              centerTitle: false,
              title: SvgPicture.asset(
                'assets/ic_instagram.svg',
                color: primaryColor,
                height: 25,
              ),
              actions: [
                IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(
                    Icons.mail,
                    color: Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 0, 191),
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(() {
                      Navigator.of(context).push(
                        MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => colorset(),
                        ),
                      );
                    });
                  },
                ),
                IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(
                    Icons.mail,
                    color: Color.fromARGB(255, 1, 132, 255),
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {
                    d = Color.fromARGB(255, 1, 132, 255);
                    setState(
                      () => d = Color.fromARGB(255, 1, 132, 255),
                    );
                    // d:Color.fromARGB(255, 1, 132, 255);
                    // setState(() {
                    //   d:
                    //   Color.fromARGB(255, 1, 132, 255);
                    // });
                  },
                ),
                Text(''),
              ],
            ),
```

Code u see change this line in utils:

```
 Color d = Color.fromARGB(255, 233, 229, 8);
```

Comment: Where was `d` declared and where is it used?

Comment: If you want to persist the color change through session restarts, you need to save it somewhere. For this specific use case, you could use shared_preferences

Comment: out of the all classes , i use it for most of the widget colors like: app bar color and buttons color

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Need To Save The State Of The App in A Storage File Or Db, Then Load The Stored State And Use It On App Start.
I Would Suggest [Hive](https://pub.dev/packages/hive) For Being Fast, Simple And Reliable.
Create An AppState Class And [Generate Hive Adapter](https://pub.dev/packages/hive_generator) To Save Object And Get/Set The Hive To The Current App State
It Works With All Platforms With Some Special integration for Web Using [flutter Hive](https://pub.dev/packages/hive_flutter)